# Is this number prime or composite?Prove your answer

Tags: prime-numbers, geometric-progressions

Is the number  $1111...$($91$ times $1$) prime or composite?  I have tried to break it into multiples of 10,but that just gave me a huge binomial expandum.

Comment: You have to show your attempt in answering the question. Think whether 91 being composite can be used to show it is not prime

Comment: Think in terms of the usual division algorithm when we divide by $1111111$  (seven $1$'s). Or else consider $\frac{10^{91}-1}{9}$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

The given number is $N=\frac{10^{91}-1}{9}$ is a repunit. Note that $10^{91}-1=(10^{13})^7-1=(10^{13}-1)(\text{some number }>1)$

Answer (score 2):

11111...(91 x 1) is a repunit, which is an integer in which every digit is one.

Properties of repunits include:

Any repunit in any base having a composite number of digits is necessarily composite. Only repunits (in any base) having a prime number of digits might be prime. This is a necessary but not sufficient condition.

For example,

R35(b) = 11111111111111111111111111111111111 = 11111 × 1000010000100001000010000100001 = 1111111 × 10000001000000100000010000001,
since 35 = 7 × 5 = 5 × 7. This repunit factorization does not depend on the base b in which the repunit is expressed.

R91 is a repunit with a composite number of digits (91)

Therefore, R91 is a composite number.

Comment: ...91 is divisible by 3?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Sorry, no it is not...I have removed the incorrect information.